# Access denied for user on MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

I have a single user for two databases on my website. First and older database DB_A is real database while newer DB_B is just for testing purposes.

My user, let's call it USER_X has all privileges (except 'DROP') on both of them and I'm sure that my username, password and DB name are all written correctly within PHP.

When connecting to DB_A and throwing
    `if(!mysql_select_db($dbname)) echo mysql_error();`
I get nothing, in other words, everything works fine.

When connectin to DB_B and throwing the same thing, I get
    `Access denied for user 'USER_X'@'localhost' to database 'DB_B'`.

Once again, I'm sure my credentials are correct and that I have all privileges on the DB_B database.

Anyone has an idea what's going on in here?

Thanks!

EDIT:

PHP v.5.2.17

MySQL v.5.0.96

Comment: "I'm sure my credentials are correct" well they are not

Comment: Just read [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html) carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MySQLi` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php - `MySQL` is deprecated.

It would be really useful to see your actual code!

Anyway, the following are from http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php

I suggest trying them, if you still get an error, then check username, password and DB spelling are ok.

**Object oriented style**

```
$mysqli = @new mysqli('localhost', 'fake_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

// Works as of PHP 5.2.9 and 5.3.0.
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
     die('Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
```

**Procedural style**

```
 $link = @mysqli_connect('localhost', 'fake_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

 if (!$link) {
     die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
 }
```

Comment: So, here is the code with MySQLi

     `$dbhost = 'localhost';`
     `$dbuser = 'username';`
     `$dbpass = 'password';`
     `$dbname = 'user_databaseName';`

     `$con = @mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);`
 <br>
     `if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {`<br>
     `   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());`
     `   exit();`
     `}`

     `mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");`

Comment: Yeahm scram that indentation sh*t that doesn't work. Anyway, I get "Connect failed: Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' to database 'user_databaseName'" as a result.

Comment: Comments are one line. I just tested the above on XAMPP and it worked flawlessly. What are you trying to do this on? Cpanel?