# MySQL: Access denied for user to database

Tags: mysql, sql, heroku, cleardb

I'm trying to create a database on my remote sql server - clearDB - on Heroku. I connected with this:

```
mysql --host='<<cleardbhostname>>' --user='<<lsdj234>> --password
```

My username and password are obtained from the result from running heroku config. When I tried to run

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb;
```

I got this:

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user '<<lsdj234>>'@'%' to database 'mydb'
```

When I ran SHOW GRANTS for current_user I got:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO '<<lsdj234>>'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*asfe4545235' WITH     MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 3600 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 10 |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `heroku_ljl4455lkj`.* TO '<<lsdj234>>'@'%'
```

What is happening? How do I resolve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access denied for user on MySQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24593262/access-denied-for-user-on-mysql-database)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only database that your user can access (and even create) is heroku_ljl4455lkj
It can't create any other databases.

Comment: In the case of importing: This also means that if your `.sql` contains the instruction to `CREATE DATABASE` and `USE`, then you might have to remove those lines.